# Python - How to change the value in a dictionary based on user input? ("Shut the Box" game)

Tags: python, dictionary, input

Extreme novice working on my first program using some Python basics.  I'm attempting to create the "Shut the Box" table game where the player attempts to eliminate a row of numbers (1-10 in this case) by rolling a pair of dice and then removing numbers based on the sum of the dice roll.

In my program, I have a dictionary of the Board (theBoard) and I want to change various values in the dictionary based on which numbers the user inputs to remove.  For example, user rolls a 5, they input 5 (but also could input 2 and 3) to be removed from the board, so the board is now 1-2-3-4-X-5-6-7-8-9-10.

Current code below, you'll see at the end where I'm attempting to check if the input is in the dictionary.  I want to check if the input is in the dictionary, then, if it is, I want to change that value into an X:

````
#setting up the Board to show which number slot we're in, which will have an integer
#until it is selected by the user to be removed from the board, then it will be 'X'

theBoard = {'one': '1', 'two':'2', 'three': '3', 'four': '4', \
            'five':'5', 'six': '6', 'seven': '7', 'eight':'8', 'nine': '9', \
            'ten': '10'}

#printing the visual of the board, starts with showing each integer 1 thru 10

def printBoard(board):
    print(board['one'] + '|' + board['two'] + '|' + board['three'] + '|' \
          + board['four'] + '|' + board['five'] + '|' + board['six'] + '|' \
          + board['seven'] + '|' + board['eight'] + '|' + board['nine'] + '|' \
          + board['ten'] + '|')


#first attempt at coding a dice roll
diceRoll = random.randint(1, 6) + random.randint(1,6)

print('Welcome! Here is your board, let\'s get started.')
printBoard(theBoard)

print('To begin, roll the pair of dice by typing \'r\'.')


rollOne = input()

#the user input triggers a dice roll
if rollOne == 'r':
    print('You rolled a ' + str(diceRoll) + '.  Now choose which \
numbers to remove from the board.')
    print('Here\'s the board again, you can type a single number, or multiple \
numbers separated by a commma to remove them from the board.')
    printBoard(theBoard)

newBoard = input()

if str(newBoard) in theBoard:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')```
````

Comment: Are you required to use a dictionary? A list might be easier to implement?
theBoard = ['1', '2', '3', '4', ...]; theBoard[newBoard] = 'X'

Comment: If you require it to be a map, you might need to remap ?
theBoardMap = {"1": "one", "2": "two", ...}; theBoard[theBoardMap[newBoard]] = 'X';

Comment: I was following a tic-tac-toe exercise and used some learnings from that to make this, hence the dictionary.  I will see if a list makes this easier!